# getClan.then is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have a script that I wrote to scrape a element off a page in a function and then call for the function later.

(I am using javascript, node.js, axios, and cheerio)

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require ('cheerio')

var clanName = ''
var clanID = 5402
const page_url = 'https://www.brick-hill.com/clan/' + clanID

getClan = async function getClanName() {
  const { data } = await axios.get(page_url);
  const $ = cheerio.load(data);
  const header = $('body > div.main-holder.grid > div:nth-child(2 > div.card > div.top > span)');
  const name = header.find('.clan-title').each((i, element) => {
    const nameElement = $(element);
    const nameText = nameElement.text
    console.log(nameText)
  })
}
console.log(page_url)

getClan.then(function(result) {
  console.log(nameText)
})
```

But the thing is, its giving me an error:

TypeError: getClan.then is not a function

I can't figure out whats wrong with the code. Send help!

Comment: Why aren't you using a `const/let` before the identifier of your function?

Comment: You have to actually call functions... `getClan().then(...)`

Comment: Sorry everyone i'm new to javascript and i'm just figuring this out, but thanks for the help so far.

Comment: No problem, Just ask if there was a specific reason why you didn't enter const or let.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ---------------- Read my comments carefully ----------------
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require ('cheerio')

var clanName = ''
var clanID = 5402
const page_url = 'https://www.brick-hill.com/clan/' + clanID

const getClan = async function getClanName() { // used const here to solve the problem
  const { data } = await axios.get(page_url);
  const $ = cheerio.load(data);
  const header = $('body > div.main-holder.grid > div:nth-child(2 > div.card > div.top > span)');
  const name = header.find('.clan-title').each((i, element) => {
    const nameElement = $(element);
    const nameText = nameElement.text
    return nameText  // returned nameText
  })
}
console.log(page_url)

getClan().then(function(result) { // you have to invoke the function with ()
  console.log(result) // logged result
})
```

Comment: Thanks Faruk! I totally forgot to define the function with const haha and I've really never used the .then part so thanks!